# how do i add the numbers returned by for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I need to add all the results of montoClean. any ideas? Thanks!!

```
for(e=0; e< montos.length; e++) {
    monto = montos[e].innerHTML;
    montoClean = Number(monto.replace('$','').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.').replace('.00', ''));
}
```

Comment: Start with `0` outside the loop, then use `+=`?

Comment: Use jquery: https://github.com/cbrandolino/jQuery-basic-arithmetic-plugin

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
montos.reduce(
  (sum,mon)=>
    sum + Number(
      mon.innerHTML.replace('$','').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.').replace('.00', '')
    ),
  0
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `montoClean` variable before for-loop

```
montoClean = 0;
for(e = 0; e < montos.length; e++) {
    monto = montos[e].innerHTML;
    montoClean += Number(monto.replace('$','').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.').replace('.00', ''));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let total = 0;
for(e=0; e< montos.length; e++) {
    monto = montos[e].innerHTML;
    montoClean = Number(monto.replace('$','').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.').replace('.00', ''));
    total +=montoClean
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a variable before the loop, say, `let totalValue = 0;`.

Then, you should add to that number in the loop, so at the end of your for loop: `totalValue += montoClean`

Answer (score 0):

Should just be able to set montoClean = to itself + the new result. Each iteration will include the previous total and add the newest number, resulting in a sum of all iteration results.

```
 for(e=0; e< montos.length; e++) {
     monto = montos[e].innerHTML;
     montoClean = montoClean + Number(monto.replace('$','').replace('.', '').replace(',', 
 '.').replace('.00', ''));
 }
```

Comment: Or just use `+=`.

Comment: Using += I would arguable is more preferable. The += operator translates to:

    x += y yields x = x + y

Either would work however.

Comment: But the left-hand side would be only evaluated once, it’s less verbose, and more readable.